# how would I place data inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method that returns some text I would like to place all the text inside a textbox, how would I do that? This is what my function looks like:

```
function MethodName() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")",
     data: JSON.stringify(),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg) {
     }
  });
}
```

This is where I would like to place:

```
<textarea id="someText"></textarea>
```

I have a menu e.g.

```
<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li id = 'testbx1' class="list-group-item active">text</li>
    <li id = 'testbx2' class="list-group-item">Documents</li>        
    <li id = 'testbx3' class="list-group-item">Music</li>
    <li id = 'testbx4' class="list-group-item">Videos</li>
</ul>
```

On click id `testbx1` id ='someText' will appear and inside id='someText' data from database will be displayed. I have strongly typed model

Comment: `$('#someText').val(YourText)` to set value

Comment: If your server is returning text, you don't want to specify `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX options. jQuery is going to expect the server response to be JSON in that case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("someText").value=msg;
```

or by jquery

```
$("#someText").val(msg);
```

Comment: do i place the above code in success handler?

Comment: I am using `$("#someText").html(msg);` in my respond body I am getting the data but it doesnt show inside textarea?

Comment: @User911 sorry, i updated my answer please use `.val(msg);` not `.html(msg);`

Comment: Inside the box  it shows [object Object]. What does that means

Comment: @User911 means the data comes from server is json object

Comment: You can try `$("#someText").val(msg[0]);` this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365857/how-would-i-place-data-inside-a-textbox#comment37677933_24365857

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti its not working I am still getting `[object Object]` inside the textbox

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti I did but I am yet getting Object object message in my `Response body` I have all the data. I try removing `                data: JSON.stringify(),` but it still gives me object object

Comment: @User911 can you call `alert(JSON.stringify(msg));` and tell me its response inside the success

Comment: @Govind Singh Nagarkoti It says `[{"Id":0"Column1":"Column1","Column2":"Column2" etc....}]` do i have to specify `msg` anywhere?

Comment: @User911 if you want to print `Column1`  use `.val(msg["Column1"]);` and same for any other

Comment: @User911 if you want as it is complete json then `.val(JSON.stringify(msg));`

Comment: Ok I tries column1 I get another error `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` I am returning as json? in my controller I am mentioning `return Json(staff, "text/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: There was a problem with textbox if i use table it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would put text into a `textarea`:

```
document.getElementById("someText").value = msg;
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('#someText').val(msg);
```

**Update**

If you're insisting on the complete code, try this:

```
function MethodName() {
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")",
     data: JSON.stringify(),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg) {
       $('#someText').val( JSON.stringify(msg) );
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted, this is the only correct answer as of writing.

Comment: +1 for you. your solutions address the problem, don't know why the down vote too :/.

Comment: @shennan your method works but it returns everything in my respond body. The data are not clear, what if I just want to get column1 I tried `$('#someText').val( JSON.stringify(column1) );` but it gives me `{}` empty results?

Comment: @User911 I don't know what data you're returning so I can't be sure, but you could try `$('#someText').val( JSON.stringify(msg.column1) );`. Be mindful that your list of *wants* is growing as time goes on. Accept an appropriate answer and create another SO question for any further issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

On your success callback just use this code:

```
 success: function (msg) {
     $("#someText").val(msg);
 }
```